# Windows 10 Anniversary Update File Icons gone

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, icons

Since I installed Windows 10 Anniversary Update, my icons for file types in Explorer are missing. Also desktop shortcuts for some programs are changed to a default (unknown?) icon.

See the attached picture:

[image]

I tried [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/) solution but it did not work for me.

Comment: A screenshot might help.  Have you tried to roll back to Version 1511 to see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot. Rolling back is not an option since it's a developer computer and we use the long filename feature in Anniversary Update.

Comment: You can't roll back as a test?  If you can't do that, my other suggestions I have, can't be done either

Comment: What would be your other suggestion?

Comment: One suggestion try reinstalling Office and Acrobat.  Without knowing of rolling back to version 1511 fixes the problem my other suggestions are not worth even mentioning